# Improve SQL statement in mysql to run faster. I want to merge field but merge on different rows

Tags: mysql

Why does this code take a long time to run?

```
SELECT
   concat((select Sname from member order by rand() limit 1),
   Ssurname) as tee
FROM member
```

But This code is very fast to run

```
SELECT
   concat(Sname,
   Ssurname) as tee
FROM member
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every result row returned by your first example, MySQL must produce another row from which to `CONCAT()` `Sname`, with a custom (random) order.  Because `order by rand()` is used, the whole table must be reordered randomly for every row in your table.  That is likely to be a very expensive operation, since the result of the subquery cannot be cached.

In the second example, a simple rowset is returned.  `Sname` and `Ssurname` are concatenated from columns in the same row.

I ran an `EXPLAIN` on a similar query, having one indexed column concatenated against a non-indexed subquery.  MySQL is using a temporary table to compute the subqueries.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT CONCAT(g_userName, (SELECT g_fullName FROM g2_User ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)) FROM g2_User;
+----+----------------------+---------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type          | table   | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                           |
+----+----------------------+---------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY              | g2_User | index | NULL          | g_userName | 98      | NULL |    5 | Using index                     |
|  2 | UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY | g2_User | ALL   | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL |    5 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+----------------------+---------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
```